# adjust divs after the div whose position is transformed

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm adjusting a div 50% up but the divs after it still display on their position.

```
.banner-action-card {
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

<mat-card class="banner-action-card" fxShow.lt-sm="true" fxHide>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <h2 fxFlexAlign="center" >Abc abc abc
    </h2>
    <a class="c-link foreground-color-blue">Select</a>
  </div>
</mat-card>
<nav fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutWrap 
       class="dashboard-nav" ngClass.xs="dashboard-nav-xs">
</nav>
```

translate(0, -50%) is great since it nicely keeps the div aligned even in responsive design but how can I move the divs after it to appear without any gap in between.

Updated question with html and css. I want nav element to also move up as my banner-action-card moves up.

Comment: Do you have a snippet so we know what you actually did and trying to do?

Comment: You need to use an alternative method such as `margin-top: -50%` if you want following context to reflow based on it. As you've discovered, translate just visually moves the item.

Comment: thanks @delinear. but is there a way to calc half of the current height of element and set it as top margin?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little directive to handle this. May be someone  can benefit from this. so now transform: translate(0, -50%) is not needed in css. Here is the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTranslateY]'
})
// sets the top margin to move an element up
export class TranslateYDirective implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('style.marginTop.px')
  marginTop: number;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.marginTop = -(this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight / 2);
    }
  }
```